# Disabling dialogs in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

[image: ckeditor]

Hello all,

I'm using CKEditor in a rails application with the gem from https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor, and would like to remove the image upload feature. The CKEditor documentation only tells you how to remove elements from a dialog.

I've tried creating a simple toolbar config like so.

```
config.toolbar_mini = [
  ["Bold",  "Italic",  "Underline",  "Strike", "Subscript",  "Superscript"],
];
```

The editor I get with this config is as seen in the picture. I need to get rid of the image button in the toolbar (towards the end on the right of the toolbar).
Has any of you been able to do this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js and comment out what you don't need in the config.toolbar array. It is important you paste the whole contents of the file in to override the default config and just change what you need. You've bene configuring a mini toolbar.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  // config.language = 'fr';
  // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.allowedContent = true;

  // Rails CSRF token
  config.filebrowserParams = function(){
    var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
        metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
        params = new Object();

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
      meta = metas[i];

      switch(meta.name) {
        case "csrf-token":
          csrf_token = meta.content;
          break;
        case "csrf-param":
          csrf_param = meta.content;
          break;
        default:
          continue;
      }
    }

    if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
    }

    return params;
  };

  config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
    var queryString = [];

    if ( !params ) {
      return url;
    } else {
      for ( var i in params )
        queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
    }

    return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
  };

  // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
  CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var content, upload;

    if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
      content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
      upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

      if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
        upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
        upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
      }
    }
  });

  // Toolbar groups configuration.
  config.toolbar = [
    // { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
    // { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    // { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    // { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
  ];

  config.toolbar_mini = [
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] }
  ];
};
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a ton! I also found out you can simplify the config file down to this. `code`     CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
    {
        config.toolbar = 'mini'

        config.toolbar_mini =
            [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
                { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'BulletedList' ] }

            ];
        
        config.autoParagraph = false;
    } `code`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your ckeditor config file `config.removePlugins = 'image';`